# openssl/RSA example

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa

where can i find the openssl/rsa examples 
as they said in the link
[OpenSSL: RSA Encryption/Decryption, key generation & key persistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10779027/openssl-rsa-encryption-decryption-key-generation-key-persistance/12653722#comment17071616_12653722)

Comment: [The source code, of course](http://openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download source code of OpenSSL and unpack the archive. Look at the directories inside:

1. [source-dir]/apps
2. [source-dir]/demos (I especially recommend to look at files in: **[source-dir]/maurice**)

I hope that helps.